# React.js App SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

After deploy react.js application on server I am getting error in contact form as in title. On localhost the form worked without any errors. The problem occurs just after clicking the sumbit button on the form. Then you can see the error in the console. Do any of you see any error in the code below? Where can I look for a solution to this error?

Live version of the contact page

[Contact page](https://delightart.co/contact)

ContactForm.js

```
const ContactForm = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const { name, email, subject, business, datetime, launch, message } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      subject: subject.value,
      business: business.value,
      datetime: datetime.value,
      launch: launch.value,
      message: message.value,
    };
    let response = await fetch("https://delightart.co/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the response body of `fetch` is not in JSON format, so when you
use `response.json()`, it threw the error. So you need make sure whether `response` is a JSON, either you can use it without calling `response.json()` or use `JSON.stringify()` in the backend service to turn the data into JSON format before sending it.

You can check `Response` apis in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response.

And `response.json()` inherits from `body.json()`, so you can check it for more details. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json